# Detect bigram collection on a very large text dataset

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I would like to find bigrams in a large corpus in text format. As the corpus cannot be loaded at once in memory and its lines are very big, I load it by chunks, each 1 kb

```
def read_in_chunks(filename, chunk_size=1024):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = filename.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
```

Then I want to go piece by piece through the corpus and find bigrams and I use the gensim Phrases() and Phraser() functions, but while training, my model constantly loses state. Thus, I tried to save and reload the model after each megabyte that I read and then free the memory, but it still loses state. My code is here:

```
with open("./final/corpus.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as r:
    max_vocab_size=20000000
    phrases = Phrases(max_vocab_size=max_vocab_size)
    i=1
    j=1024
    sentences = ""
    for piece in read_in_chunks(r):   

        if i<=j:
            sentences = sentences + piece

        else:
            phrases.add_vocab(sentences)
            phrases = Phrases(sentences)
            phrases = phrases.save('./final/phrases.txt')
            phrases = Phraser.load('./final/phrases.txt')

            sentences = ""
            j+=1024
        i+=1
print("Done")
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the two lines...

```
        phrases.add_vocab(sentences)
        phrases = Phrases(sentences)
```

...that 2nd line is throwing away any existing instance inside the `phrases` variable, and replacing it with a brand new instance (`Phrases(sentences)`). There's no chance for additive adjustment to the single instance.

Secondarily, there's no way two consecutive lines of `.save()`-then-immediate-re-`.load()` can save net memory usage. At the very best, the `.load()` would be unnnecessary, only exactly reproducing what was just `.save()`d, but wasting a lot of time and temporary memory loading a second copy, then discarding the duplicate that was already in `phrases` to assign `phrases` to the new clone.

While these are problems, more generally, the issue is that what you need done doesn't have to be this complicated.

The `Phrases` class will accept as its corpus of `sentences` an iterable object where each item is a list-of-string-tokens. You don't have to worry about chunk-sizes, and calling `add_vocab()` multiple times – you can just provide a single object that itself offers up each item in turn, and `Phrases` will do the right thing. You *do* have to worry about breaking up raw lines into the specific words you want considered ('tokenization').

(For a large corpus, you might still run into memory issues related to the number of **unique** words that `Phrases` is trying to count. But it won't matter how arbitrarily large the number of items is – because it will only look at one at a time. Only the accumulation of *unique words* will consume running memory.)

For a good intro to how an iterable object can work in such situations, a good blog post is:

[Data streaming in Python: generators, iterators, iterables](https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/)

If your `corpus.txt` file is already set up to be one reasonably-sized sentence per line, and all words are already delimited by simple spaces, then an iterable class might be as simple as:

```
class FileByLineIterable(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as src:
            for line in src.readlines():
                yield line.split()
```

Then, your code might just be as simple as...

```
sentences = FileByLineIterable('./final/corpus.txt')
phrases = Phrases(sentences, max_vocab_size=max_vocab_size)
```

...because the `Phrases` class is getting what it wants – a corpus that offers via iteration just one list-of-words item at a time.

Note:

- you may want to enable logging at the INFO level to monitor progress and watch for any hints of things going wrong
- there's a slightly more advanced line-by-line iterator, which also limits any one line's text to no more than 10,000 tokens (to match an internal implementation limit of `gensim` `Word2Vec`), and opens files from places other than local file-paths, available at `gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence`. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence

(Despite this being packaged in the `word2vec` package, it can be used elsewhere.)

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. I modified a bit the class to handle data by chunks and not by lines as my data lines are very big and it works like a charm. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad it's working! But in general you shouldn't have to use chunks, unless each line is incredibly long. (And if that's the case, it might make sense to have a separate standalone preprocessing step that breaks long lines, to keep the Python code more simple, and/or recognize other natural breaks in the source material. Or, use an approach like that in the `LineSentence` class I mention, whose source code can be reviewed inside `gensim`.)